# Proper way to wait that fragment is visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, google-play-services

I am using fragments for my turn based game, how can i be sure that a fragment is visible and added to context in this kind of async-function before executing any code in that fragment?

```
fun respondToRematchInvitation(invitation : Invitation) {
    if (winFragment.isVisible) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("Accept invitation for rematch?")
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure?")
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
            turnBasedMultiplayerClient.acceptInvitation(invitation.invitationId)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Invitation accepted succesfully")
                    isDoingTurn = false
                    gameFragment = GameFragment()
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, gameFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()
                    onInitiateMatch(it) //error happens here
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    createFailureListener("Accepting invitation failed")
                }
        }

        val dialog : AlertDialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
```

Now in `onInitiateMatch(it)` i have some code that modifies gameFragment, for example possible receiving opponents game data and other initialization. Simply using `if (gameFragment.isVisible)` or `if (gameFragment.isAdded)` is not enough because that way `onInitiateMatch(it)` function might not be executed if that if-statement returns false.

Should I use threads for this?

Comment: override onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that executing `supportFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()` solved the problem, I thought first it was not the a solution for the problem.